# Top and bottom border colors disappear on specific border-radius

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I was learning to use logical CSS properties with borders and their radii. After a certain radius of a specific corner of an element, the colors of the top and bottom borders get changed to those of left and right borders.

I have tried using logical (block/inline/start/end) as well as physical (top/bottom/left/right) properties; if we change the `border-end-end-radius` or `border-bottom-right-radius` of the element lesser than `32.3px`, the colors of the top and bottom borders change from `#012345` to `#f00` (which is the same as that of left and right borders).

```css
.border {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-block: solid 20px #012345;
  border-inline: solid 30px #f00;
  border-start-start-radius: 24px;
  border-start-end-radius: 50%;
  border-end-start-radius: 100%;
  border-end-end-radius: 32.3px; /* decrease this value to reproduce the error */
}

.border2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-top: solid 20px #012345;
  border-bottom: solid 20px #012345;
  border-left: solid 30px #f00;
  border-right: solid 30px #f00;
  border-top-left-radius: 24px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 32.3px; /* decrease this value to reproduce the error */
}
```

```html
<div class="border">border logical</div>
<div class="border2">border physical</div>
```

Why does this inconsistency happen? How can I set the radius of the bottom-right corner lesser than the breaking value?

*Note: I have observed that this error does not show up on Firefox. It shows on chromium-based browsers (Chrome, MS-Edge-chromium).*

[Similar CodePen playground to verify](https://codepen.io/deekeh/pen/mdxgQpb?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested these 2 borders. They did change the colors but my minimum radius to display correct colors was 32.7 px (I suppose it has something to do with the monitor size).

Actually, I zoomed in/out the page, and found the border displayed correct colors at some particular magnifications. Also, I've noticed that the larger "width" and "height" are, the smaller "px" you can choose to display correct colors. It looks like a common issue of Edge and Chrome.
Here's 2 workarounds for you:

1. Adjust the width, height and radius, and make them collaborative against any possible magnification.
2. Replace the "coded" borders with border images.